# Semantic Issue using Reachability

Tags: ios, semantics, reachability

I have been stumped by this **Semantic Issue** warning for a week now, and it is becoming frustrating.
Anyone willing to take a look at it?  Any advice will be graciously taken. <3

**WebViewController.m**

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize backbtn;
@synthesize forwardbtn;
@synthesize webAddy;
@synthesize activityIndicator;
@synthesize loadingLabel;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    loadingLabel.hidden = YES;
    backbtn.enabled = NO;
    forwardbtn.enabled = NO;
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    if([Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable)
{ 
        UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@"Sorry" 
                            message:@"You are not connected to the internet. Please Try again"
                            delegate:nil 
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                            otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        [av setDelegate:self];
        [av show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webAddy];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The *Warning* redirects me to the 20th line. 
The compiler tells me: 
"*Class method '+currentReachabilityStatus" not found (return type defaults to 'id')*"

If more information is needed, please let me know. Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Where did you get the Reachability implementation from?

Comment: The **@implementation Reachability** is located in the

Reachability.m File.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_5).

The `- (NetworkStatus) currentReachabilityStatus;` is not a class method.

Comment: I understand currentReachabilityStatus is a NSObject, but what do I need to do to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus]` instead of `[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus]`.

`currentReachabilityStatus` is an instance method, so you need an instance first.

Comment: The same error remains, except instead of telling me: 

"Class method '+currentReachabilityStatus' not found"

It tells me... 

"Class method '+reachabilityForInternetConnection' not found"

Comment: @Sambo post your `Reachability.h` please.